# while loop gets only the last row when displaying videos on popup window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm new at programming and I'm having some trouble fixing this part of my code for displaying cases of different families for my charity website, I would be so grateful if anyone could help me. Here is my code..

```
    <div id="Families"><div id="arrow"></div>
    <?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "help_someone";

//Creating connection for mysqli

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

//Checking connection

if($conn->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM familjet";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  ?>

<div class="cases"><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="350" height="200">'?>               
<button type="button" class="show-modal1">SHIKO VIDEON</button>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.showYtVideo.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.show-modal1').on('click', function () {
                $.showYtVideo({
                    videoId: '<?php echo $row["videoID"];?>'
                });
            });
        });  
</script>
   <p><?php echo $row["pershkrimi"];?></p>
       </div><!--end cases-->
   <?php }
?>  
  </div><!--end Families-->
```

The problem is that when I click the button it shows only the last videoID and as a result I get only the video for my last record in database. The rest of the code works just fine. Can someone suggest what should I do?

Comment: I would suggest separating your fetching of the information from the database and your view.  I think that's what throwing you off.  You also have a lot of javascript that get's created for ever record in your database.  You should think about making a list of objects.  Then work on the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are looping the script elements. And probably the last script echo'd by your loop is the one being executed.

Put the scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` tag and make them static content.

```
<body>
 <?php
  //php loop here ...
 ?>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.showYtVideo.js"></script>
</body>
```

For the next fix, we're going to make use of data-attributes, every time we click a button with class .show-modal, we get the data-video-id attribute and use it to show the video element;

```
<body>
 <div id="Families">
  <div id="arrow"></div>
  <?php
   $server = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $pass = "";
   $dbname = "help_someone";

   //Creating connection for mysqli
   $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

   //Checking connection
   if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM familjet";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die(mysqli_error());
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo"<div class='cases'>";
    echo"<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['image'])."' width='350' height='200'>";
    echo"<button type='button' class='show-modal' data-video-id='".$row['video_id']."'>SHIKO VIDEON</button>"; //use data-attribute, data-video-id
    echo"<p>".$row["pershkrimi"]."</p>";
    echo"</div>"; //close cases
   }
  ?>
  </div><!--end Families-->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.showYtVideo.js"></script>

  <script>
   $(document).on("click",".show-modal",function(){
    //get video from data-attribute
    var videoId = $(this).attr("data-video-id");
    alert("Your video ID:"+videoId);

    //show video
    $.showYtVideo({
     videoId: videoId
    });
   });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Do mark this the correct answer if it did help. Thank you also! ;D